# Какой смысл вкладывался в слово "дурак"?

Tags: лексика, семантика, литература, фольклор

Где-то здесь мне попадался вопрос об этимологии слова "дурак". И, если не ошибаюсь, там ответили, что так назывались шуты.
Но, если судить по русским сказкам, в это слово вкладывался и другой смысл.

*У старинушки три сына:

Старший умный был детина,

Средний сын — и так и сяк,

Младший вовсе был дурак.*

Лейтмотив Ивана-дурака встречается в сказках очень часто, при этом ни разу не показаны его "дурацкие" поступки. Напротив, он всегда герой, он побеждает чудовище, спасает всех и женится на царевне.
В чем же тогда он дурак?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наиболее ранние фиксации слова дурак в русском языке – это собственные имена. Например, в 1495 году жил крестьянин Корнилко Дурак.

Как нарицательное это слово употребляется в русско-английском разговорнике, который составил в 1618 – 1619 годах англичанин Ричард Джемс. У Джемса это слово употребляется в значении ‘государев шут’. В XVII веке оно уже активно употребляется и в привычном нам значении. В «Житии» протопопа Аввакума говорится владычице, "уйми дурака тово" (о воеводе Пашкове).

В первой русской грамматике, изданное в Оксфорде в 1689 году немцем Георгом Вильгельмом Лудольфом, есть немало примеров употребления этого слова: алты (= аль ты) дурак, дураки крадут и др.. Для этимологов корень дур-, к которому относятся слова дурак, дурь, дурной, до сих пор остается трудной задачей.

На происхождение имени Дурак есть несколько точек зрения:

1. Этимологический словарь замечает, что слово дурак образовано с помощью суффикса –ак от древнерусского дурый – глупый, являющегося общеславянским словом индоевропейского характера.
2. Другая версия – от латинского gardus – глупый, бестолковый (отсюда такие слова, как гордость и глупость, древние русичи считали эти слова синонимами, а Русская православная церковь относит гордость к смертным грехам). От этого же корня музыкальный термин dur – мажор.
3. Третья версия: от латинского dura – суровый, твердый, прочный; а применительно к человеку жесткость – упертость – признак недалекого ума (отсюда, возможно, пословица «Упрямство – вывеска дурака»). Представление о глупости на Руси связывалось с образом твердой головы (лба).
4. Еще одно толкование значения и появления имени Дурак следующее. На Руси ребенок часто до 11-13 лет носил ложное, не настоящее имя, чтобы, прельстившись красивым словом, черти и другая нечистая сила не возгорелись вдруг желанием похитить малыша. Нужно было имя-оберег. А в семьях очень часто детей называли по очередности их появления на свет: Первыш, Другак, Третьяк, Четвертой, Пятой, Шестой (Шестак) и так далее примерно до 13-го включительно. Слово Другак с течением времени вполне могло упроститься в Дурак.

Comment: Понравились ваши этимологические версии, особенно 4. Интересная! Вот только Другак - второй (в Укр. сохраняется числительное и сейчас - "другий" ), а в сказках дурачок обычно третий. Но это мелочи.

Answer (score 2):

> Лейтмотив Ивана-дурака встречается в сказках очень часто, при этом ни разу не показаны его "дурацкие" поступки. (...) 
> В чем же тогда он дурак?

Предполагаю, что **дурак** -- это необычное, нестандартное поведение. "Не от мира сего". Ведёт себя не так, как обычные люди.

Я имею в виду сказочного Ивана-дурака.

Answer (score 2):

Иванушка-дурачок имеет отношение к юродивым. Это не моя мысль, я просто вспомнила, что-то раньше слышала. Юродивым на Руси многое разрешалось, они могли говорить правду о ком угодно, им все это сходило с рук, как и шутам.

В словаре Даля: ЮРОДИВЫЙ, безумный, божевольный, дурачок, отроду сумасшедший; народ считает юродивых Божьими людьми, находя нередко в бессознательных поступках их глубокий смысл, даже предчувствие или предведенье.

В некоторых сказках Иванушка-дурачок и выглядит соответствующим образом: "рот в глупой улыбке растянул", "слюни текут" и т.п.

Хорошая статья об Иванушке-дурачке здесь: http://ec-dejavu.ru/i/Ivan_durak.html Автор ссылается на Д.С.       Лихачева.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел ответы, версии хорошие, но причинно несостоятельные. Не был "дурак" изначально обделенным умом ни разу, а просто был молодым, поскольку был он именно младшим сыном, "оставшимся" (тур. durak) или скорее "последним", возможно и "дрУгим".

А мог беззаботно валяться на печи и бездельничать потому, что являлся приоритетным наследником, и задниця (наследство) большей частью отходила ему, как младшему. Об этом есть в "Русской Правде". "Умным" братьям же приходилось вовсю вкалывать, да и женились они в самой сказке на серебро от проданных коней. Кстати, у поморов до сих пор встречается в обычаях: дом - младшему сыну, конь - старшему.

Поэтому не только по причине лени дурак позволял себе так бездельничать. Очень может быть, что отсюда и пошло значение "шутовства", а там и "глупость" на подходе, ежели ничего не делать и не развиваться.

Рыскающим в поисках других толкований могу посоветовать Даля, там большая статья по "дураку", много народных поговорок. Еще смотрел Михельсона, где нашел неявную отсылку к "молодо-зелено". Фасмера не советую, у него не получилось оформить "дуранду", а ответ, на мой взгляд, близок - остатки от зерна, оставшиеся части.

Comment: Дочитал до турецкого слова, дальше не стал. "Несостоятельные" (с) у вас версии, товарищ. Голословие и вульгарная этимология.  А советовать тут ничего не надо, советчиков и так хватает. Вы аргументировано что-нибудь сказать можете, кроме бессодержательного перечисления авторитетов?.

Comment: Не вижу смысла препираться с тем, кто даже не соизволил прочитать написанное. На вопрос темы я ответил.

Comment: Вот и я так думаю, что пр6епираться с теми, кто отвечает про турецкие слова, не читая вопроса, препираться нет смысла. Гнать надо поганой метлой.

Comment: Занимайтесь зарабатыванием своей репутации в другом месте. Куда только модераторы смотрят.

Comment: Модератора вызывали?

Answer (score 0):

> Но, если судить по русским сказкам, в это слово вкладывался и другой смысл.

Отнюдь. Не другой, а обратный, от противного. Знаете, как сейчас лысого лохматым зовут. Или последнего бедняка - Князем.
Это т.н. "охранное", обережное имя (кажется даже есть точное названия, вот не помню). Такие имена давали ребенку, чтобы отпугнуть нечистую силу. Отсюдв все эти Золотухи, Тупицы, Безруковы. Невзоровы (невзор=урод)... Чтобы ребенок рос умным, ему давали имя Дурак или Тупица.

Кстати, Дурак - он обычно младшенький. Считалось, что первые дети наследуют красоту, физическую силу - средние, ум - младшие; от тех качеств. которыми в момент рождения в полной мере обладают родители.

Comment: Интересно про младшенького. Про имя-оберег согласен. Только, понимаете, не имя это. А качество.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос о "смысле"... Вы меня не поймёте если начну разъяснять о том, что "смысл" - это уже косвенное. Зачем о смысле, о косвенном, когда можно дать точное определение? 
 
Дурак - человек, который возомнил себя: важным, деловым, солидным... и ведёт себя соответственно; хочет выставить свою значимость, но для других людей не воспринимается таковым. 
Проверочное слово - придурок.  
Придурок - человек, который умышлено ведёт себя так, будто он значим, нарочито предстаёт не таким, каким является на самом деле. 
Дурак и придурок - эти названия даны русскими людьми по поведенчиским признакам.  
Разница в умышленности и неумышленности поведения.